# Wiremock Docker Container not using the supplied port (instead using 8080)

Tags: docker, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am using WireMock Docker image and spinning off the container using it. I can verify the container is up and running but after looking at container logs, looks like it is still running on `8080`? At least, I am not able to access **Wiremock** using `localhost:9999/__admin`

Create Wiremock container:  `docker run -d -p 9999:9999 my-registry.com/rodolpheche/wiremock --verbose`

Verify container:  docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
7b9847734cd4        my-registry.com/rodolpheche/wiremock   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        8080/tcp, 8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9999->9999/tcp   elegant_elion
```

[image]

Comment: Is it accessible on port `8080`?

Comment: It is not accessible from 8080

Comment: Because port exposed by container is `8080` and you're exposing `9999:9999`, which is wrong. You need to do `9999:8080` as shown in answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `docker run -it --rm -p 9999:8080 rodolpheche/wiremock` in order to run the **Wiremock** as clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/rodolpheche/wiremock). It will be accessible using this url: `http://localhost:9999/__admin`

Comment: I would like to run on a different port and not 8080. I was able to solve my issue, going to post in few mins

Comment: @Code-Strings added support for different port

Comment: @Code-Strings Basically `Wiremock` exposes 8080 and you can map it appropirate port on host.

Comment: I tried to do that but Wiremock was always running on port 8080 - the fix was to append --port 9999 after  rodolpheche/wiremock

Comment: I've tried the same command is accessible on `9999`. Anyways you got your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue (appending --port 9999):

```
docker run -d -p 9999:9999 my-registry.com/rodolpheche/wiremock --verbose --port 9999
```

Answer (score 0):

After some days struggling with "HttpNoResponseException" because of this problem, the answer of Code-Strings saved me. For some reason that I really couldnt get, wiremock was starting always on port 8080, although it was configured to start on port 8089. I went to docker, copied 'docker run' command of the container, added --port 8080 to the end of the command and it worked. Thank you!